# How to Desrialize JSON using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

I am currently using Json.Net to deserialize my JSON. I now have the following situation:

I am getting the following JSON response:

```
{"Success":false,"Errors":{"UserName":"User Name already registered","EmailAddress":"Email Address already registered"}}
```

I want to parse it into this type:

```
public class CustomJsonResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string[] Errors { get; set; }
}
```

Using Json.net, I tried doing this:

```
CustomJsonResult regResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomJsonResult>(json);
```

But this is not working, I get the error **Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.String[]'.**

How can I fix this? (using Json.Net or any other library)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to convert a dictionary into an array. Try replacing your `string[]` with `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Comment: @Robert Dondo do mean that the `Error` object may have different fields or that there could be more `Error` objects in the `Errors` field in the JSON?

Comment: The Error object may have extra(or less) fields. I hadn't considered this when I made the initial post.

Comment: Well, then this is a better answer to meet what you need :-)

Answer (score 3):

`Errors` is not an array of string, it is an `object` with `UserName` and `EmailAddress` as it's property.

```
{
    "Success":false,
    "Errors":{
        "UserName":"User Name already registered",
        "EmailAddress":"Email Address already registered"
     }
}
```

well, you can create another class to store the error message

```
public CustomJsonError
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Then refactor the class

```
public class CustomJsonResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public CustomJsonError Errors { get; set; } // I'm not sure if the property should be named as Errors
}
```

BTW, will error contain an array / list of errors?

**Update**

Well, you can use `Dictionary<string, string>` (see other answer) or create a custom class for the Error. See http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializingCollections.html for serializing and deserializing Collection to and from JSON.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your "Errors" in your JSON doesn't match what it's trying to deserialize to. It should be something like this:

```
public class CustomJsonResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public ErrorType[] Errors { get; set; }
}

public class ErrorType
{
     public string UserName {get;set;}
     public string EmailAddress {get;set;}
}
```

If you want to change the JSON to match, it should look something like this:

```
{"Success":false, "Errors": ["User Name already registered", "Email Address already registered"]}
```

Otherwise you may need some intermediate mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScriptSerializer from standard .NET framework library System.Web.Extensions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string,int>>("{ a: 1, b: 2 }");
            Console.WriteLine(dict["a"]);
            Console.WriteLine(dict["b"]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```